# A different meaning of あらためて?

Tags: words

Context: Girl asked guy to tell her after school if he wants to walk home with her

Guy in his head: 返事ちょうだいってことは… あらためて俺から誘えってことだよな

I've been told that a translation for the 2nd line is "After all, the invite has to come from me"
But I cannot seem to find any definition to that effect. Is there another definition or is the meaning different from the translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

改めて is a lexicalized adverb derived from the verb 改める, whose meanings include “to mend”, “to correct”, etc. It doesn’t just mean “again” but has an implication of “in a more proper way”.

In this context, the girl suggested that they walk home together, but she is expecting a clear reply from the guy. He takes it as meaning she wants him to ask her from his end, unambiguously. He might or might not have asked her earlier. If he did, it must have been done in a casual and not so obvious way.

Answer (score 2):

It’s somewhat difficult to tell for sure without the backstory but the suggested translation looks a bit off. To me it sounds more like:

“By saying she needs the answer… does it mean the invitation has to come from me *again*?”