# Is 改めて mean meaning 2 (deliberately, formally etc) used?

Tags: meaning, nuances

改めて言われっとなんか...

the character thinks this after being told something unpleasant. Now as I know means "again" so "being told this again is a bit...", however is the meaning 2 改めて "intentionally", etc ever used?

Comment: This could be close to "formally": https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95974/43676

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to [jisho's](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%94%B9%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6) entry.  I'm not sure where they're pulling these secondary definitions from of "intentionally; deliberately" are being taken from.

These meanings are not suggested to me by the dictionaries I have.  Nor do these meaning appear in the example sentences that [jisho offers](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%20%23sentences) or [other examples](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%94%B9%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%20%23sentences)

From my 和英辞典, I have the following:

> **1** again. 改めて電話します。I'll call you again. 彼の努力には改めて感心させられた。I was impressed again with his strenuous efforts.
>
> **2** 改めていうまでもなく... needless to say...

This second example just seems to reinforce the idea of repeating something already understood.

From my 角川国語辞典,

> ①新しく。新たに。

And from my junior high dictionary:

> ①やり直して。もう一度。②今さら。

You might consider looking at the verb 改める also for clues about the meaning.  改める can also mean to *examine* something.  Perhaps from the perspective of this verb, there might possibly be occasions where the translation *intentionally* could make sense.  I can't think of natural ways of doing that.  Perhaps one of the native speakers here can think of such situations.

**Update**

I've also dug out my Nelson's Kanji dictionary and my massive Kenkyusha Japanese-English Dictionary.  In neither is any meaning corresponding to *intentionally* found.

Comment: Jisho claimed on every page that they're using "*JMdict, Kanjidic2, JMnedict and Radkfile dictionary files*" as their sources.

Comment: @AndrewT. Indeed.  That just pushes the question to JMdict.  Where did they come up with their definitions, since the same *erroneous* definitions appear there.  Whether they are truly *erroneous* or not, I'm not saying.  But, the electric database is clearly not in agreement with my older print resources, which really aren't all that old (some 20 years others 10 years).